# ¿Como modelar una base de datos para una tienda en el área de ingreso de productos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy desarrollando un sistema con php y mysql para una tienda de abarrotes, pero tengo una duda que no puedo resolver, en la parte de ingreso de productos estos tienen medidas es decir (unidad,libra,carton,funda) por ejemplo un aceite puede ser ingresado por unidad o por cartón en el cual vienen una x cantidad de unidades, es precisamente eso lo que no se como hacerlo en la base es decir crear una tabla medidas o algo asi pero hay que considerar que un carton de leche no es lo mismo que un carton de aceite es decir traen unidades diferentes, pero no tengo la idea clara de como hacerlo.

Answer (score 2):

Es bastante general lo que se puede decir sobre esto. Puedes aplicar lo que mejor se acomode a tu situacion.

- A nivel de producto (existencia) se puede almacenar la unidad compra/venta, multiplo y unidad base (ej: `caja, 12, unidades`).
- Puedes tener multiples unidades de compra (compras en cajas de 12) y de venta (vendes en unidades o cajas completas).
- Ciertos productos pueden tener unidades de compra distinas a la de venta. (Compras un `rollo, 200, mts` y vendes por pulgadas) lo importante es tener una unidad base comun para simplificarlo. Sobre todo si controlas existencia.
- En otro lugar se pueden almacenan las unidades si algunas pueden tener conversion entre ellas
- Los precios venta y costo tambien deben definirse por unidad (Ej: costo $12 x caja, venta $2 x unidad)

La implementacion de las operaciones deben considerar estas conversiones. Es un tema muy amplio para tratarlo por aqui.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, estoy iniciando en esto y la verdad se me complica mucho, lo que quiero hacer es que al ingresar una compra por ejemplo una caja de aceite en el stock de mi tabla producto se me actualice el valor de unidades que trae la caja registrada en compras.